# How to get rid of these black insects/eggs on potted spinach? Neem oil?

Tags: insects, spinach

[image: 1]

These insect/eggs are there on some leaves of the potted spinach. These seem to be causing holes in leaves as well as curling. How do I get rid of them? Water spray? Neem Oil (Azadiratchin)? Or something else?

[image]

Comment: The holes look like slug damage; the curling is probably from these insects.

Comment: @Jurp Good catch. Chewing insects eat pieces of leaves. Sucking insects leave damage like the discoloring within the leaves in the black bug (aphids?) domain.

Comment: Can these be inside the soil?

Answer (score 1):

Soap and water at 5ml per liter is very effective against soft bodied insects.  I think the black things in the picture are small caterpillars but they could be insect [frass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frass).

Either way soap and water is fast, easy, inexpensive and does not require anything more than a rinse with water for a food plant.

Try and see if the damage stops. If it doesn't check at night for slugs as Jurp suggests.

Comment: I have cleared all the big leaves and stems. Will the soap water mix affect the potting soil? Should I add vegetable oil? I have a dishwashing bar, I can use that in dilution right?

Comment: @Sam no problems with the soil, I use liquid dish soap, the key is very dilute. You don't need much, rinse with water a few minutes after spraying will remove the soap residue

Comment: This one is okay right? https://www.amazon.com/Vim-Dishwash-Gel-500-Lemon/dp/B00U2DV4AA This is the one available here

Comment: @Sam as long as it dissolves in water you are good to go

Comment: I sprayed the mixture on the leaves and stems trying to avoid the soil. One somewhat long legged bug did come out in one pot and I killed it.